I want to restrict the input into a range of cells in a spreadsheet to a capital Y without using a data validation list
Using a data validation list would take input longer as there is only one choice. I've seen this formula, but it doesn't seem to work.
=COUNT(MATCH(MID(D2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(D2))),1),allowed&"",0))=LEN(D2)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
